# Can I transfer my C: drive to any other PC and boot sucessfully?

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to transfer the C: drive to any other PC? How do I make it bootable and runnable on every PC without any problem or error?

I'm used to Acronis but I have found many problems with this.

Comment: I would seriously consider what problem you are actually trying to solve & ask that question. 3 posts, all hinting at the same thing, not one of which is likely to get a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can physically move it from PC to PC no problem. However, you'll likely run into issues with drivers, etc, and the system will most likely not boot fully. I suggest you take a look at Windows 8.1's Windows To Go feature.

Comment: Sir tell me what problems i will see

Comment: Windows 7 is not intended as a portable OS.  It is designed to be installed on a single computer (and licensed as such).  While Linux will generally do a good job figuring out what it needs and booting on a different computer, Win 7 doesn't work that way.  You install and configure it for a given computer and that is what it expects to find.

Comment: Mr tetsujin i am seen boot failure peoblem with transfarring c drive to dissimilar hardware.  Im seen there reason is drivers.  Suggest me solutions.

Comment: @HarshitPanchal - With Win 7, even if you solve the problem that you think is drivers, it will be temporary.  Microsoft will see the new hardware and may disable the OS as a license violation.  Also, if you change the drivers and configuration, it will stop working in the original computer.